# Can't deploy to my EC2 instance with capistrano 3 anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

When I try to deploy my application with capistrano it stucks after the command:

```
~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do ruby --version
```

This is how the console print looks like:

```
root@srv:/var/www/project# cap staging deploy
(in /var/www/project)

    require "capistrano/scm/git"
    install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

rvm 1.29.12-next (master) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
system
```

Nothing happens after this. It worked fine for a long time but since I've started bundle install (or maybe someone else changed anyhting) the deployment doesn't work anymore. Here's an excerpt of the log file:

```
  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  INFO START 2021-02-11 13:39:04 +0100 cap staging deploy
  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 DEBUG [08de3cd7] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm version as deploy@x.xxx.xx.xx
 DEBUG [08de3cd7] Command: ~/.rvm/bin/rvm version
 DEBUG [08de3cd7]       rvm 1.29.12-next (master) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
 DEBUG [08de3cd7]
 DEBUG [08de3cd7] Finished in 0.773 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [17018c10] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm current as deploy@x.xxx.xx.xx
 DEBUG [17018c10] Command: ~/.rvm/bin/rvm current
 DEBUG [17018c10]       system
 DEBUG [17018c10]
 DEBUG [17018c10] Finished in 0.303 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [41115234] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do ruby --version as deploy@x.xxx.xx.xx
 DEBUG [41115234] Command: ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do ruby --version
```

As you can see I am using rvm 1.29.12 with ruby 2.5.1p5. Maybe someone had the same problem or can give me a hint what to do. I have been searching for a solution since hours...

Answer (score 0):

Please try to check your setup first using the below command and check what the error is

```
cap staging deploy:check
```

Comment: Thank you but I already tried that and it stucks again. Same trace as stated above.